# access value and key in json object javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

i am using firebase to store data which is in this [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DakAL.jpg)

and am using java script to retrieve the value of each date / time stamp and its key to plot it using apex chart which requires data to be in array form but i keep getting it in json object form even if i parse it it is in this form

```
 {…}
​
"-LeXZ024bCLM5h44sESQ": Object { "2019-5-10 20 25": 48, value: 13 }
​
"-LeXZ1DXWyJeWmChbYGR": Object { "2019-5-10 20 25": 83, value: 14 }
​
"-LeXZ2IJjdX3SJE7J0Q1": Object { "2019-5-10 20 25": 25, value: 15 }
​
"-LeXZ3RwJ8ojPpUOnxU5": Object { "2019-5-10 20 25": 24, value: 19 }
```

i tried to parse it to array , but i keep getting the exact same format in array form i want an array to hold only the values which are 48 , 83 ...etc

here is the code i tried :

```
 firebase.database().ref('Facilities').child('Library').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var jsonObject = snapshot.val();
    console.log(jsonObject);


     var parsed_2 = Object.keys(jsonObject).map(function(_) { return jsonObject[_]; });  
     console.log(parsed_2);
});
```

Comment: can you show us some code that you tried?
we could try to pinpoint the problem in your code

Comment: i added the code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
this.db.list('').valueChanges().subscribe((values: any) => {
      var firstobj: [0, 1];

      firstobj= values[0];

      firstobj[Object.keys(firstobj)[0]];
    })
```

Comment: i cannot use [any] key word i am programming in plain javascript without support for type script